# forward sms to new number on the same phone

Tags: sms, t-mobile

I have an unlocked Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.4. I am switching phone service providers from T-Mobile to Ting wireless. is there a way that phone calls and (more importantly) text messages can be forwarded to my new number?

Comment: Posting this as a comment instead of an answer as I am not sure if it is a viable solution, but you may be able to port your old number into Google Voice, then set up call and text forwarding to your new number.

Comment: Call forwarding is carrier dependent since it may involve charges. For forwarding text messages, it is possible by simple automation. If interested in this approach, please revert